# Filtering Date()-1 to Date() with time between Dates

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I would like to filter the date and time between today and last day. I'm going to use it to see the cut off between two users.

This is the code I got and I can't get the time fixed. I want it to be 6:00pm from the last night to 9:00am today.

```
WHERE (((tbldtr.Date)=Date()-1) 
  AND (("time")>=#12/30/1899 18:0:0#)) 
  OR (((tbldtr.Date)=Date()) 
  AND (("time")<=#12/30/1899 9:0:0#))
ORDER BY tbldtr.Date;
```

Comment: What is the Data Type of the column Date (a very bad field name)? Also what is Time?

Comment: its tbldtr.Date and for time is tbldtr.Time

Comment: So Date and Time are two different fields?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that your `Date` column is a datetime column and that you are not storing your times separately.

```
WHERE tbldtr.Date >= dateadd("h", 18, dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, now())-1, 0))
   and tbldtr.Date < dateadd("h", 9, dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, now()), 0))
```

Or

```
WHERE tbldtr.Date  >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24
  AND tbldtr.Date < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
```

Use whichever you find easier to read.

EDIT:

I tested like this in the immediate window

```
?#7/29/2014 7:00 PM#  >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24  AND #7/29/2014 7:00 PM# < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
True
?#7/29/2014 5:00 PM#  >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24  AND #7/29/2014 5:00 PM# < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
False
?#7/30/2014 7:00 PM#  >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24  AND #7/30/2014 7:00 PM# < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
False
?#7/30/2014 5:00 AM#  >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24  AND #7/30/2014 5:00 AM# < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
True
```

If your date and time columns are separate you can jsut add them together to make a single datetime value (and since there is no such data type in Access SQL as `Date` or `Time` I assume you have a way of keeping dates out of times and times out of dates. This is not the best design but you must have a reason for going down this road)

```
WHERE (tbldtr.Date + tbldtr.Time) >= dateadd("h", 18, dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, now())-1, 0))
   and (tbldtr.Date + tbldtr.Time) < dateadd("h", 9, dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, now()), 0))
```

Or

```
WHERE (tbldtr.Date + tbldtr.Time) >= dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)-1) + 18/24
  AND (tbldtr.Date + tbldtr.Time) < dateserial(year(now),month(now),day(now)) + 9/24
```

And if you want to do a sanity check you can flush out the dates from your times just in case.

```
?tbldtr.Time - dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, tbldtr.Time, 0),0)
```

and the times out of the dates

```
?dateadd("d", datediff("d", 0, tbldtr.Date, 0),0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help brad
But the code you gave seems not to be working
it only shows the file on the current date
it is easier if im going to store time separately?
heres the code that works to open the file from the last day till today.. but i cant figure out how im going to filter the date from the last day to current day.. :(
thx for the help again :D

WHERE (((tbldtr.Date)=Date()-1)) OR (((tbldtr.Date)=Date()));

Comment: @BryanNapatGuinto I added some more